# Remove XML node if the inner tag matches value using Linq in C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq

```
<column>
    <format>boolicon</format>
    <heading>Attachment</heading>
    <prop>urn:schemas:httpmail:hasattachment</prop>
    <type>boolean</type>
    <bitmap>1</bitmap>
    <width>10</width>
    <style>padding-left:3px;text-align:center</style>
    <editable>0</editable>
    <displayformat>3</displayformat>
</column>
<column>
    <heading>From</heading>
    <prop>urn:schemas:httpmail:fromname</prop>
    <type>string</type>
    <width>68</width>
    <style>padding-left:3px;text-align:left</style>
    <editable>0</editable>
    <displayformat>1</displayformat>
</column>
<column>
    <heading>Subject</heading>
    <prop>urn:schemas:httpmail:subject</prop>
    <type>string</type>
    <width>326</width>
    <style>padding-left:3px;text-align:left</style>
    <editable>1</editable>
</column>
```

I want to delete column node if the heading is equal to "Subject"

```
(from node in xdoc.Descendants("column") select node).ToList().ForEach(x=>x.Remove());
```

Trying to select node only if it heading matches "Subject".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

I think, a simple XPath can help you

```
xdoc.XPathSelectElement("//column[heading='Subject']").Remove();
```

PS: Don't forget to include *using System.Xml.XPath;*

Comment: You could change this to XPathSelectElements (plural) to remove multiple matches.

Comment: @DaveMackersie Yes I could. But the xml in question isn't clear about it (I don't think he has a dataset with duplicate column names). So I chose this way. The xml isn't even valid since it misses a root node

Answer (score 3):

You can add simple `where` clause to filter only `<column>` elements having child `<heading>` equals `"Subject"` :

```
(from node in xdoc.Descendants("column") 
 where (string)node.Element("heading") == "Subject" 
 select node
 ).Remove();
```

Or using method syntax :

```
xdoc.Descendants("column")
    .Where(n => (string)n.Element("heading") == "Subject")
    .Remove();
```

Comment: Replace .First with .Where to get all the matching cases. This works due to the Remove() extension method, which @EZI's solution depends on as well.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357554(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @DaveMackersie You're right, I got impression that we can only call `Remove()` on `XNode` not `IEnumerable<XNode>` because of OP's original code. BTW, @EZI's solution doesn't depend on this because he is using `XPathSelectElement` which return single result

Comment: Oh, right, I was looking at the documentation for XPathSelectElements